# Retrieve content from latin_swedish_ci and store it into utf8_general_ci

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, type-conversion

I want to retrieve content from latin_swedish_ci and store it into utf8_general_ci.
Does it breaks any character in my existing content ??

Comment: please attach latin_swedish_ci string to post, do you want to convert that?

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't have any issues converting from `latin_swedish_ci` to `utf8_general_ci` because all characters in [`latin_swedish_ci`](http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.dec8_swedish_ci.html) are also available in [`utf8`](http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_general_ci.european.html). Problems only arise when there are characters in the source collation that do not exist in the destination collation.

Converting the other way, however, will create problems because there are many characters that won't be able to be converted directly since they don't exist in `latin_swedish_ci`. If ever in that situation, you could store them (for example) as their corresponding HTML entities instead of the actual characters. Choosing an appropriate character encoding, of course, would be the better answer.